# Wordpress: Editing a Post, 99% CPU?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a blog with ~15k posts, and a DB size of 14.4M.

The website works blazingly fast from the front end, but post-edit and post-listing screens hang - either loading partially or not at all.

Even worse, the entire server gets bogged down after trying...

Examining the process manager showed that `/public_html/wp-admin/edit.php` or `/public_html/wp-admin/post.php` (post-listing and post-edit, respectively - yeah I know they seem backwards) was eating 99% CPU.

I experienced this problem on a 3rd tier Bluehost VPS, so I upgraded to a Heart Internet Hybrid 250 (12core, 28gb ram) to try and mitigate the problem - no dice :/

Any help getting this resolved is greatly appreciated - telling clients they have to edit pages through phpMyAdmin is not an option :)

edit: clarification on hanging processes

edit2: Running MySQL processes:

```
Id      User    Host        db  Command     Time    State   Info

338     leech.. localhost   leech.. Sleep   1959            NULL
426     tmhp_.. localhost   tmhp_.. Sleep   581             NULL
433     root    localhost   NULL    Sleep   132             NULL
441     root    localhost   NULL    Query   0       NULL    SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Process Example:

```
Pid     Owner   Priority    CPU %   Memory %    Command
29447   tmhp        0       99.8    0.6         /usr/bin/php /home/tmhp/public_html/wp-admin/edit.php
```

Edit3: This might be pertinent:  When on the add-new or post-edit pages the title loads and is editable, but the content editor loads halfway. Additionally, the text appears but is white and only visible when highlighted...

Edit4: The MySQL process from user tmhp goes away after killing the hanging (99%) process causing the issue.... I think we might be onto something here...

Edit5: This conversation has moved to [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117647/editing-a-post-99-cpu)

Given enough time (~3-5 minutes), the post-edit page will load fully and the process will terminate.  This doesn't seem to happen with the post-listing page, however.

Additionally, I've narrowed down the problem on the post-edit page to the page-attributes meta-box.

As a short term remedy I've created a plugin which does the following:

```
//Remove some features of pages so editing is faster
if (is_admin()) :
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'page', 'side');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
endif;

function remove_page_attribute_support() {
    remove_post_type_support('page','page-attributes');
}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_page_attribute_support' );


// Remove the Posts and Pages menus from the admin screen
function custom_admincss() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
           #menu-pages{display:none !important}
           #menu-posts{display:none !important}
         </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admincss');
```

Comment: How many posts are getting loaded on the page you're trying to load?

Comment: [Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list). But the first thing, is disabling all plugins and swapping the theme to Twenty11/12/13

Comment: 99% procent off PHP application/websites performance issues are caused by bad querys (most likly without indexes)... so you need to look into  SHOW FULL PROCESS in MySQL to see it there are long running queries and analyse them with the EXPLAIN statement.

Comment: @matthewpavkov the post listing page works now, can show all pages, but still results in the server hang (99% CPU persisting even when the listing page is closed)

Comment: @brasofilo thanks, am reading over those resources now.  It's a brand new install with no plugins running - theme is set to 2012

Comment: @RaymondNijland Much appreciated, but I don't see an error there. I put the info in my edit above

Comment: @RaymondNijland - just updated it if you're just seeing this now

Comment: @JakeBlank Can't be "a brand new install", 2013 is the default theme since >three months. ;-)

Comment: wouldnt a bad query have mysql using cpu time, not php?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - lol, got me there.  I change every new site over to 2012 by default, even if I have no plans on using it.  2013 hurts my eyes... note: this is a manual change

Comment: @JAL - that's what i thought too, unless perhaps the code is waiting for a response from the mysql server?

Comment: Waiting for a response wouldn't consume excessive CPU.

Comment: @JAL - The MySQL process from user tmhp goes away after killing the hanging (99%) process causing the issue...

Comment: have you tried to disable post revisions?

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO - I did on the old server, not on this one yet.  I will do that now and report back

Comment: @jakeBlank that makes sense that it would kill the mysql connection it has open whenm the script ends (PHP frees its resources)... but that doesn't mean php was using the DB actively during the intense CPU time

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO - unfortunately no :/

Comment: @JAL - thanks for the clarification.  given the "sleep" command i'd assume the issue isn't with mysql...

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JAL - done!  if you wish to follow this thread please do so [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117647/editing-a-post-99-cpu) .... thanks!

Comment: @JakeBlank may that options will help you
-disable all plugins
-open new post page and insert new post then modify (for checking) 
-comment your hooking functions for post like `add_action` or `add_filter`
-create new db and modify `wp-config` for new db connection  ( just testing )
-download latest wordpress and `wp-config` connect with your original db and then check it.

Comment: @RameezSOOMRO - already did everything you suggested - even went as far as getting a new box at a different host...

Comment: Well if it's not database related problem.. i don't have Wordpress knowledge for an good reason so i can't help you..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - It's all good, I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Found the problem, it actually stems from the WP-Core.  See below for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pinned it down to the hierarchy arg for the [pages post-type:](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

> **hierarchical**
>
> (boolean) (optional) Whether the post type is hierarchical (e.g. page).
>
> Allows Parent to be specified. The 'supports' parameter should contain 'page-attributes' to show the parent select box on the editor page.
>
> Default: false
>
> ***Note:** this parameter was planned for Pages. Be careful, when choosing it for your custom post type - if you are planning to have many entries (say - over 100), you will run into memory issue. With this parameter set to true WordPress will fetch all entries of that particular post type, together with all meta data, on each administration page load for your post type.*

Now, any idea how one can go about removing hierarchical support for pages w/o overwriting the core?

Comment: I just find out how Wordpress handle hierarchical pages. I couldn't believe that it selects all pages (and all fields)to make a paginated list. This is madness. I know that, make a tree-like list can be complicated, and one of the solutions is to do it in similar way. But,  what is the purpose to gets the pages contents?